# How much more expensive are hydraulic disk brakes compared to mechanical disk brakes?

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, price

How much more expensive are hydraulic disk brakes compared to mechanical disk brakes?

I'm asking this to determine which parts contribute to price differences across different models and brands. Is that a big factor? A general estimate would be also fine. And I'm comparing this in low-end mountain bikes.

Thanks

Comment: @Swifty thanks for the edit. But this comment that I added later was left out of your edit: "A general estimate would be also fine. And I'm comparing this in low-end bikes." was this removal necessary?

Comment: Sorry that happened because I started my edit before you did but was slower to type! So overwrte them by default, not intentional. But even so I think the question was fine without.

Comment: now I see how helpful the addition was to the question but I can't edit my comment ><

Comment: (TL:DNR, Cheap hydraulics cost no more than mechanical brakes but add perceived value. A bike with Hydraulics commanding a higher price has little to do with the cost of the brakes)
Generally pricing of bikes is based on valued added potential up sell rather than cost. If you ever buy a bike, you will notice the never ending 'for just another $ you can have highly desirable feature X". The salesman stops at one price point higher than the cash he thinks you have, then tells you that 'one feature' won't make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on wether you are talking about disc brakes on a drop-bar bike or disk brakes on a flat bar bike. Hydraulic disc brakes with integrated shifters (on drop-bar bikes) are pretty expensive. Generally I made the experience that for the same price you can get a flat bar with hydraulic or a drop bar with mechanical (e.g. Bulls Daily Grinder 1 vs Canyon Commuter 5.0).

On flat-bar bikes the difference seems to be fairly small when comparing hydraulic vs mechanical disc brakes but this varies a lot, since there are also mechanical and hydraulic brakes of vastly different quality.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is kind of helpful. Seeing your reference to bike types, I updated my question again. I have mountain bikes and mount-city hybrid bikes in mind.